# Why python regex match function matches that special character?

Tags: python, regex, match, special-characters

I have regex pattern `"^[a-zA-z0-9]+$"`
As I understand it should describe a word or something like that.
I try to verify a string like `"counter"`:

```
re.match("^[a-zA-z0-9]+$", "counter")
# Result: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000AA2053C578> #
```

If I have special character like `"/"` it won't match (returns nothing).

```
re.match("^[a-zA-z0-9]+$"), "coun/ter")
```

But if I try this:

```
re.match("^[a-zA-z0-9]+$", "coun[ter")
# Result: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000AA2053C440> #
```

It matches again and I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex should be:

```
re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$', "coun[ter")
```

not

```
re.match('^[a-zA-z0-9]+$', "coun[ter")
```

When you have `A-z` it captures everything from `A` (ASCII 65) to `z` (122) and that also matches `[` (91).

Comment: @anubhava You have a good sight!

Comment: This is a simple question caused by the typographical error, which are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). [Please do not answer off-topic questions.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285623/3622940) Take a __[tour]__.

Comment: I have seen many regex problems like that when `-` is unescaped or someone's understanding of character class is different. This can very well be one of those, though typo can also be a reason for this regex. Besides I've added an explanation why `[` was allowed but `/` wasn't.